# Optimizer hyper-parameter assignment in Keras

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm using Keras to model GAN algorithms and I was testing with different variations of optimizers.
When first assigning the values I used the format:

```
optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)
```

Then I changed the format to:

```
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
```

Surprisingly I found the two outputs to be somewhat different. As far as I can understand, since the function parameters are in the order as `keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)` which is shown in the documentation, the above two formats should be exactly the same assigning 0.0002 to the learning rate and 0.2 to the beta_1 parameters.

Has anyone else noticed this as well? If so what can be the reason for this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://keras.io/optimizers/

Comment: Are you sure that difference didn't occure due to randomness?

Comment: also, your comments don't match code wrt to beta_1 parameter

Comment: Randomness from random initializations as well as from non-deterministic execution of tensorflow operations can have a large impact in some algorithms. I highly doubt that there is some Python bug that resulted in arguments being passed incorrectly.